# Java Ask the user for password 3 times

Tags: java, loops

I have a real newbie question.
I want to ask the user for a password 3 times. After 3 times, if the wrong password is still entered, I want to exit the block.

This is what I have at the moment. But I'm stuck with the final statement. If the password is not correct the first time, the final 'false' will overwrite the 'true' statement in the while loop.

```
public boolean checkOwnerPassword2()
    {
        String password = "123";
        String s = userInput();
        if(s.equals(password))
        return true;
        else
        {
            int i = 0;
            while(!(s.equals(password)) && i < 2)
            {
                if(s.equals(password))
                return true;
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Try again");
                    s = userInput();
                    i++;

                }   
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Somewhere else Im using the following code:

```
if(checkOwnerPassword2())
addPrizeToList();
else
System.out.println("sorry you can't add prize!");
```

This is my edited version:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way you can do like this.

```
    public boolean checkOwnerPassword2() {
        String password = "123";
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter password");
            String s = userInput();
            if (s.equals(password)){
                return true;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

from your code

```
  while(!(s.equals(password)) && i < 2)
```

replace to like this

```
  while(i < 2)
```

this if condition will take care of the password verification

```
 if(s.equals(password))
   return true;
```

Comment: Let say I get the password right after by 2nd go. And it exits the while loop and the IF statement. Wouldn't the last 'return false' over right the return true?

Comment: the `return true` will be the last executed statement, instead of `return false`.

Comment: Why not replace the `while` loop with a `for` loop?

Comment: @Prabhakaran Makes sense, though you write `while (i < 3)` which checks 4 times and the OP only wants to check 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

problem with your code is that when you enter correct password

!(s.equals(password)) evaluates to false in a way (!(true)) . And you have used end so first condition evaluates to false and second true. And program left the while loop and returns false.

Answer (score 0):

The times of trying should be stored in database. 
like this:

username | password | details | password_try_times

Once the user try a wrong password, password_try_times should add 1.
And if the user login successfully, the password_try_times will be set to 0.

If you use Spring-security, you can add this process to the `UserAuthenticationProviderService` method.

Hope this will help:)